# SQL grouping Aggregation on Agragate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to tweak this query:

```
SELECT WeekOf =  
    LEFT(Convert(varchar(12), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101', 
        CONVERT(date, 
            CONVERT(CHAR,DATEADD(D, d.[date], '1800-12-28'),101), 101)), '19000101'), 101),6)  
            + RIGHT(YEAR(MAX(d.date)),2),
              ' Mx' + MAX(s.first) + ': ' + --Number of Records for User A 
              ' Mn' + MIN(s.first) + ': ' + '' --Number of Records for User B

,[Count]=COUNT(d.ccode)
FROM lntmuid.document d
JOIN lntmuid.staff s ON d.staff = s.init
WHERE (DateDiff(YEAR, d.date, GETDATE()) = 0)
AND ccode = 'SUM'
GROUP BY DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101', d.date), '19000101'), s.first
```

I'm trying to not only get the total record count but also the split of who did the most and the least for each week.  My desired output would be:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║  WeekOf   ║         Breakdown          ║ Total Count ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 03/09/15  ║ Mx DAVID:6 Mn Rich:4       ║          10 ║
║ 02/23/15  ║ Mx Emily:8 Mn Obi:2        ║          10 ║
║ 01/12/15  ║ Mx Iliana:6 Mn Bob:9       ║          15 ║
║ 02/02/15  ║ Mx Iliana:20 Mn:Steve:10   ║          30 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I was trying this:

```
 SUM(case when d.Staff = MAX(s.first) then 1 else 0 end)
,SUM(case when d.Staff = MIN(s.first) then 1 else 0 end)
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if two or more people have equal `MAX` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the query in a subquery and the take the sum. Something like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(col1),
        SUM(col2),
        otherCols
FROM
(
    SELECT  CASE WHEN [Staff] = MAX([first]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS col1,
            CASE WHEN [Staff] = MIN([first]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS col2,
            otherCols
    FROM yourTable 
    GROUP BY otherCols
) A
GROUP BY otherCols
```